# column "name" does not exist

Tags: postgresql, psql, jdbctemplate

I am having issue with ALIAS variable "distance" in my PSQL query. (*please ignore that I am using voutecount as distance)

```
SELECT rentalid, createdDate, votecount AS distance
FROM rental 
WHERE longitude=? AND latitude=?   
HAVING distance < 25 ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 OFFSET 30
```

The error is "distance does not exist" but I have defined distance already so I cannot tell what the issue is.

```
nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "distance" does not exist
  Position: 107] with root cause
```

---

@Maimoona Abid Okay I am not getting any error but the actual SQL command I am running is as below and I am getting any empty resultset. I believe it is because the query is actually searching RENTAL Table for longitude and latitude that I give as parameter **instead of using the parameter for calculating the distance**.

```
public List<RentalDto> selectRentalsByDistance(Double lon, Double lat) {
        var sql = """
                SELECT *
                FROM (
                    SELECT rentalid, createdDate, 
                    ( 3959 * acos( cos(radians(37) ) * cos( radians(latitude) ) * cos( radians(longitude) - radians(-122) )
                                    + sin( radians(37) ) * sin( radians(latitude) )) ) as distance
                    FROM rental
                    WHERE lon = ? AND lat = ?                                    
                ) AS subquery
                WHERE distance < 25
                ORDER BY distance
                LIMIT 30 OFFSET 0
                """;
        return jdbcTemplate.query(sql, rentalDtoRowMapper, new Object[] {lon, lat});
    }
```

Comment: Except for `ORDER BY` clauses and specific cases for `GROUP BY` clauses, column aliases from the `SELECT` clause aren't visible to the rest of the query. Another problem is that conditions in the `HAVING` clause "must unambiguously reference a grouping column, unless the reference appears within an aggregate function or the ungrouped column is functionally dependent on the grouping columns" (from [SELECT](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html) in the PostgreSQL documentation).

Comment: Is this the full real query? In the code you've shared, there isn't any aggregation clause, so it doesn't really make sense to use `HAVING`, it could be `WHERE` all the way down. In general, `HAVING` should repeat the full definition, e.g. `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT vote.id) > 25`.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález, I suspect that this is the full query since the error's location of 107 is consistent with the query as presented. A `HAVING` clause without `GROUP BY` is similar to using a non-windowed aggregate function in the `SELECT` list; i.e., all rows meeting the `WHERE` clause conditions form a single group. If the conditions in the `HAVING` clause are met, then a single row is returned; however, if the conditions are not met, then no row is returned.

Answer (score 1):

Try this approach, first create a subquery that calculates the distance alias and then filter and order the results in the outer query.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT rentalid, createdDate, votecount AS distance
    FROM rental 
    WHERE longitude = ? AND latitude = ?
) AS subquery
WHERE distance < 25
ORDER BY distance
LIMIT 30 OFFSET 0;
```

Hope it works :)

Comment: Although this query addresses the reference to `distance`, it's a poor approach since It adds complexity in the form of an unnecesary subquery. A better approach is to use a simple query with `AND votecount < 25` in the `WHERE` clause. Adding a subquery just to allow reference to an aliased column name doesn't improve clarity and actually increases the cognitive load on the reader since it becomes necessary to search the query to find the definition of `distance`.

Answer (score 1):

You get this error because you are using `HAVING` on an alias `distance` that you defined in the `SELECT` clause and this is not supported. So you have to use the `WHERE` clause instead of `HAVING` to filter rows based on the `distance` alias;

```
SELECT rentalid, createdDate, votecount AS distance
FROM rental 
WHERE longitude = ? AND latitude = ? AND votecount < 25
ORDER BY distance
LIMIT 0 OFFSET 30;
```